# Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude

Tags: python, geocoding, geo, geography

I tried implementing the formula in *[Finding distances based on Latitude and Longitude](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/)*. The applet does good for the two points I am testing:

[image]

Yet my code is not working.

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2

R = 6373.0

lat1 = 52.2296756
lon1 = 21.0122287
lat2 = 52.406374
lon2 = 16.9251681

dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1
a = (sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
distance = R * c

print "Result", distance
print "Should be", 278.546
```

It returns the distance **5447.05546147**. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Just as a note, if you just need a quick and easy way of finding the distance between two points, I strongly recommend using the approach described in [Kurt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211266/646543) below instead of reimplementing Haversine—see his post for rationale.

This answer focuses just on answering the specific bug the OP ran into.

---

It's because in Python, all the trigonometry functions [use radians](http://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions), not degrees.

You can either convert the numbers manually to radians, or use the [`radians`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians) function from the *math* module:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

# Approximate radius of earth in km
R = 6373.0

lat1 = radians(52.2296756)
lon1 = radians(21.0122287)
lat2 = radians(52.406374)
lon2 = radians(16.9251681)

dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1

a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

distance = R * c

print("Result: ", distance)
print("Should be: ", 278.546, "km")
```

The distance is now returning the correct value of *278.545589351* km.

Comment: this is true in any programming language, and also in differential calculus.  using degrees is the exception, and only used in human speech.

Comment: Word to the wise, this formula requires all degrees be positive. `radians(abs(52.123))` should do the trick...

Comment: Are you sure about all degrees (angles?) being positive? I think this is wrong. Consider if lat1, lon1 = 10, 10 (degrees) and lat2, lon2 = -10, -10 (degrees). By adding an abs() around the degrees, the distance would be zero, which is incorrect. 

Perhaps you meant to take the absolute value of dlon and/or dlat, but if you look at the dlon, dlat values in the calculation of a, sine is an even function, and cosine squared is an even function, so I don't see any benefit to taking an absolute value of dlat or dlon, either.

Comment: Just wondering if the distance above is the arc distance or plane distance between two locations?

Comment: There was a [breaking change](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog_2xx.html#breaking-changes)
Removed `geopy.distance.vincenty`, use `geopy.distance.geodesic` instead. Would you update your answer?

Answer (score 424):

The Vincenty distance is now [deprecated since GeoPy version 1.13](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog_1xx.html#id12) - [you should use `geopy.distance.distance()`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) instead!

---

Some previous answers were based on the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), which assumes the earth is a sphere, which results in errors of up to about 0.5% (according to `help(geopy.distance)`). The [Vincenty distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) uses more accurate ellipsoidal models, such as [WGS-84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System), and is implemented in [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy). For example,

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

will print the distance of `279.352901604` kilometers using the default ellipsoid WGS-84. (You can also choose `.miles` or one of several other distance units.)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please update your answer with coordinates I provided in question instead of Newport and Cleveland. It will give a better understanding to future readers.

Comment: The arbitrary locations of Newport and Cleveland come from the example geopy documentation in the PyPI listing: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy

Comment: I had to modify Kurt Peek's answer to this:
Capitalization required: `print geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(coords_1, coords_2).km 279.352901604`

Comment: You should probably use `geopy.distance.distance(…)` in code which is an alias of the currently best (=most accurate) distance formula. (Vincenty at the moment.)

Comment: You should probably use `geopy.distance.geodesic` since the distance will raise ValueError if `c1=(1, 179)` and `c2=(0,0)`.

Comment: Does this give distance or displacement? I mean does it take into account any vertical axis?

Comment: Using geopy.distance.vincenty in geopy-1.18.1 outputs: Vincenty is deprecated and is going to be removed in geopy 2.0. Use `geopy.distance.geodesic` (or the default `geopy.distance.distance`) instead, which is more accurate and always converges.

Comment: `geopy.distance.great_circle` will run twice as fast

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Vincenty is deprecated and is going to be removed in geopy 2.0. Use `geopy.distance.geodesic` (or the default `geopy.distance.distance`) instead, which is more accurate and always converges. #FYI

Comment: Update geopy 2.0.0:
`from geopy import distance` and then use
`dist = distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km` which defaults to obtaining the geodesic distance.

Comment: Use `conda install geopy -y` / `pip install geopy` to install the package

Answer (score 126):

For people (like me) coming here via a search engine, and who are just looking for a solution which works out of the box, I recommend installing [`mpu`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu). Install it via `pip install mpu --user` and use it like this to get the [haversine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

```
import mpu

# Point one
lat1 = 52.2296756
lon1 = 21.0122287

# Point two
lat2 = 52.406374
lon2 = 16.9251681

# What you were looking for
dist = mpu.haversine_distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2))
print(dist)  # gives 278.45817507541943.
```

An alternative package is [`gpxpy`](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy).

If you don't want dependencies, you can use:

```
import math

def distance(origin, destination):
    """
    Calculate the Haversine distance.

    Parameters
    ----------
    origin : tuple of float
        (lat, long)
    destination : tuple of float
        (lat, long)

    Returns
    -------
    distance_in_km : float

    Examples
    --------
    >>> origin = (48.1372, 11.5756)  # Munich
    >>> destination = (52.5186, 13.4083)  # Berlin
    >>> round(distance(origin, destination), 1)
    504.2
    """
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371  # km

    dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = (math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) +
         math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) *
         math.sin(dlon / 2) * math.sin(dlon / 2))
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    d = radius * c

    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The other alternative package is [`haversine`](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/):

```
from haversine import haversine, Unit

lyon = (45.7597, 4.8422) # (latitude, longitude)
paris = (48.8567, 2.3508)

haversine(lyon, paris)
>> 392.2172595594006  # In kilometers

haversine(lyon, paris, unit=Unit.MILES)
>> 243.71201856934454  # In miles

# You can also use the string abbreviation for units:
haversine(lyon, paris, unit='mi')
>> 243.71201856934454  # In miles

haversine(lyon, paris, unit=Unit.NAUTICAL_MILES)
>> 211.78037755311516  # In nautical miles
```

They claim to have performance optimization for distances between all points in two vectors:

```
from haversine import haversine_vector, Unit

lyon = (45.7597, 4.8422) # (latitude, longitude)
paris = (48.8567, 2.3508)
new_york = (40.7033962, -74.2351462)

haversine_vector([lyon, lyon], [paris, new_york], Unit.KILOMETERS)

>> array([ 392.21725956, 6163.43638211])
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the given Highet of one of the points?

Comment: You could simply add the height difference to the distance. I would not do that, though.

Comment: "Lyon, Paris, 392.2172595594006 km", wow the last digit is not even the size of an atom of hydrogen. Very accurate!

Comment: wow can you hep me ? , is posible obtain the corresponding  distance in decimal degrees over a custom point in map ?, ex : get the  decimal degree  for point x, y like tha distance in meters is 300 mts

Answer (score 36):

I arrived at a much simpler and robust solution which is using `geodesic` from `geopy` package since you'll be highly likely using it in your project anyways so no extra package installation needed.

Here is my solution:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic


origin = (30.172705, 31.526725)  # (latitude, longitude) don't confuse
dist = (30.288281, 31.732326)

print(geodesic(origin, dist).meters)  # 23576.805481751613
print(geodesic(origin, dist).kilometers)  # 23.576805481751613
print(geodesic(origin, dist).miles)  # 14.64994773134371
```

[geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/)

Comment: Thanks buddy for mentioning that latitude is first then longitude. Cheers!

Answer (score 20):

There are multiple ways to calculate the distance based on the coordinates i.e latitude and longitude

### Install and import

```py
from geopy import distance
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
import osrm
import numpy as np
```

### Define coordinates

```py
lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, R = 20.9467,72.9520, 21.1702, 72.8311, 6373.0
coordinates_from = [lat1, lon1]
coordinates_to = [lat2, lon2]
```

### Using haversine

```py
dlon = radians(lon2) - radians(lon1)
dlat = radians(lat2) - radians(lat1)
    
a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    
distance_haversine_formula = R * c
print('distance using haversine formula: ', distance_haversine_formula)
```

### Using haversine with sklearn

```py
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
    
X = [[radians(lat1), radians(lon1)], [radians(lat2), radians(lon2)]]
distance_sklearn = R * dist.pairwise(X)
print('distance using sklearn: ', np.array(distance_sklearn).item(1))
```

### Using OSRM

```py
osrm_client = osrm.Client(host='http://router.project-osrm.org')
coordinates_osrm = [[lon1, lat1], [lon2, lat2]] # note that order is lon, lat
    
osrm_response = osrm_client.route(coordinates=coordinates_osrm, overview=osrm.overview.full)
dist_osrm = osrm_response.get('routes')[0].get('distance')/1000 # in km
print('distance using OSRM: ', dist_osrm)
```

### Using geopy

```py
distance_geopy = distance.distance(coordinates_from, coordinates_to).km
print('distance using geopy: ', distance_geopy)
    
distance_geopy_great_circle = distance.great_circle(coordinates_from, coordinates_to).km 
print('distance using geopy great circle: ', distance_geopy_great_circle)
```

### Output

```py
distance using haversine formula:  26.07547017310917
distance using sklearn:  27.847882224769783
distance using OSRM:  33.091699999999996
distance using geopy:  27.7528030550408
distance using geopy great circle:  27.839182219511834
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Uber's H3](https://eng.uber.com/h3/),`point_dist()` function to compute the spherical distance between two (latitude, longitude) points. We can set the return units ('km', 'm', or 'rads'). The default unit is km.

Example:

```
import h3

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)
distance = h3.point_dist(coords_1, coords_2, unit='m') # To get distance in meters
```

Comment: What result do you get? The question was: *"It returns the distance 5447.05546147. Why?"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I think it doesn't make sense to answer this particular question because I answered that almost 9 years later. I aimed to offer valuable information to this thread since it appears as the top result when someone searches for `getting distance between two points using Python` on Google.

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np


def Haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2, **kwarg):
    """
    This uses the ‘haversine’ formula to calculate the great-circle distance between two points – that is, 
    the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – giving an ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between the points 
    (ignoring any hills they fly over, of course!).
    Haversine
    formula:    a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
    c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
    d = R ⋅ c
    where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);
    note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!
    """
    R = 6371.0088
    lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2 = map(np.radians, [lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])

    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2) **2
    c = 2 * np.arctan2(a**0.5, (1-a)**0.5)
    d = R * c
    return round(d,4)
```

Comment: Hi do you think there is a way to do the calcul in getting data directly from the template ?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For instance, the question was ***"It returns the distance 5447.05546147. Why?"***. How does this answer that question? What is the idea/gist? What result do you get? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56769419/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

In the year 2022, one can post mixed JavaScript and Python code that solves this problem using more recent Python library, namely, `geographiclib`. The general benefit is that the users can run and see the result on the web page that runs on modern devices.

```js
async function main(){
  let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
  await pyodide.loadPackage(["micropip"]);

  console.log(pyodide.runPythonAsync(`
    import micropip
    await micropip.install('geographiclib')
    from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
    lat1 = 52.2296756;
    lon1 = 21.0122287;
    lat2 = 52.406374;
    lon2 = 16.9251681;
    ans = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    dkm = ans["s12"] / 1000
    print("Geodesic solution", ans)
    print(f"Distance = {dkm:.4f} km.")
  `));
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide), presumably.

Answer (score 1):

(Year 2022, live JavaScript version.) Here is the code that solves this problem using a more recent JavaScript library. The general benefit is that the users can run and see the result on the web page that runs on modern devices.

```js
// Using the WGS84 ellipsoid model for computation
var geod84 = geodesic.Geodesic.WGS84;
// Input data
lat1 = 52.2296756;
lon1 = 21.0122287;
lat2 = 52.406374;
lon2 = 16.9251681;
// Do the classic `geodetic inversion` computation
geod84inv = geod84.Inverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
// Present the solution (only the geodetic distance)
console.log("The distance is " + (geod84inv.s12/1000).toFixed(5) + " km.");
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geographiclib-geodesic@2.0.0/geographiclib-geodesic.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is tagged with Python.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is with the *haversine* package.

```
import haversine as hs

coord_1 = (lat, lon)
coord_2 = (lat, lon)
x = hs.haversine(coord_1, coord_2)
print(f'The distance is {x} km')
```

Comment: What result do you get? The question was: *"It returns the distance 5447.05546147. Why?"*

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting use of mixed JavaScript and Python through a [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide) and [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) implementation to obtain the solution using Python's libraries [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) and *geographiclib* is also feasible.

I made extra effort using Pandas to prep the input data and when output was available, appended them to the `solution` column. Pandas provides many useful features for input/output for common needs. Its method `toHtml` is handy to present the final solution on the web page.

I found that the execution of the code in this answer is not successful on some [iPhone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) and [iPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad) devices. But on newer midrange Android devices it will run fine.

```js
async function main(){
let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
await pyodide.loadPackage(["pandas", "micropip"]);
console.log(pyodide.runPythonAsync(`
import micropip
import pandas as pd
import js
print("Pandas version: " + pd.__version__)
await micropip.install('geographiclib')
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
import geographiclib as gl
print("Geographiclib version: " + gl.__version__)
data = {'Description': ['Answer to the question', 'Bangkok to Tokyo'],
      'From_long': [21.0122287, 100.6],
      'From_lat': [52.2296756, 13.8],
      'To_long': [16.9251681, 139.76],
      'To_lat': [52.406374, 35.69],
      'Distance_km': [0, 0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
collist = ['Description','From_long','From_lat','To_long','To_lat']
div2 = js.document.createElement("div")
div2content = df1.to_html(buf=None, columns=collist, col_space=None, header=True, index=True)
div2.innerHTML = div2content
js.document.body.append(div2)
arr="<i>by Swatchai</i>"

def dkm(frLat,frLon,toLat,toLon):
    print("frLon,frLat,toLon,toLat:", frLon, "|", frLat, "|", toLon, "|", toLat)
    dist = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(frLat, frLon, toLat, toLon)
    return dist["s12"] / 1000

collist = ['Description','From_long','From_lat','To_long','To_lat','Distance_km']
dist = []
for ea in zip(df1['From_lat'].values, df1['From_long'].values, df1['To_lat'].values, df1['To_long'].values):
  ans = dkm(*ea)
  print("ans=", ans)
  dist.append(ans)

df1['Distance_km'] = dist
# Update content
div2content = df1.to_html(buf=None, columns=collist, col_space=None, header=True, index=False)
div2.innerHTML = div2content
js.document.body.append(div2)

# Using the haversine formula
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians, asin
# Approximate radius of earth in km from Wikipedia
R = 6371
lat1 = radians(52.2296756)
lon1 = radians(21.0122287)
lat2 = radians(52.406374)
lon2 = radians(16.9251681)
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
def hav(angrad):
    return (1-cos(angrad))/2
h = hav(lat2-lat1)+cos(lat2)*cos(lat1)*hav(lon2-lon1)
dist2 = 2*R*asin(sqrt(h))
print(f"Distance by haversine formula = {dist2:8.6f} km.")
`));


}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
Pyodide implementation<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use thanks to [Sviatoslav Oleksiv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234234/6776611).

```py
   earth_radius = {"km": 6371.0087714, "mile": 3959}

   earth_radius['km'] *
   acos(cos((math.radians(p1['latitude']))) *
   cos(math.radians(p2['latitude'])) *
   cos(math.radians(p2['longitude']) -
   math.radians(p1['longitude'])) +
   sin(math.radians(p1['latitude'])) *
   sin(math.radians(p2['latitude'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are in geographical territory (!), here is a solution using [cartopy.geodesic.Geodesic.inverse()](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/generated/cartopy.geodesic.Geodesic.html#cartopy.geodesic.Geodesic.inverse). I believe you could also use [pyproj.Geod.inv()](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.inv) to achieve something similar.

Note: cartopy uses lon-lat pairs, contrary to most other packages mentioned here.

```py
import cartopy.geodesic as cgeo

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)
coords_3 = (52.406374, 10)

globe = cgeo.Geodesic()

# Distance between two points
inv = globe.inverse(coords_1[::-1], coords_2[::-1])
print(inv.T[0]/1000)
# [279.3529016]

# Distances from one point to a list of other points
inv_2 = globe.inverse(
    coords_1[::-1],
    [coords_2[::-1], coords_3[::-1]],
)
print(inv_2.T[0]/1000)
# [279.3529016  750.45799898]
```