# Error while getting the distance between two co-ordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance, haversine

I have a `panda dataframe` with the following `schema`:

```
customer_id                                     int64
vehicle_type                                   object
pickup_place                                   object
place_category                                 object
how_long_it_took_to_order                      object
pickup_lat                                    float64
pickup_lon                                    float64
dropoff_lat                                   float64
dropoff_lon                                   float64
pickup_coord                                   object
dropoff_coord                                  object
dtype: object
```

I am trying to find the distance between the pickup and drop locations. So I initially tried using the approach here [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude) via the haversine formula. When i tried to conver the degrees to radians using

```
df_post['lat1'] = radians(df_post['pickup_lat'])
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

So i tried following the approach in the 3rd reply, using the `geopy.distance` module using the in-built function and for that created a tuple of the lat and long.

```
df_post['pickup_coord']=list(zip(df_post['pickup_lat'],df_post['pickup_lon']))
df_post['dropoff_coord']=list(zip(df_post['dropoff_lat'],df_post['dropoff_lon'])
```

But when i tried the in-built function

```
df_post['pickup_dropoff_distance']=gd.VincentyDistance(df_post['pickup_coord'],df_post['dropoff_coord']).miles
```

I am getting a new error:

```
ValueError: When creating a Point from sequence, it must not have more than 3 items.
```

Can someone help me with why either of the errors are ocurring and what is the possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for your distance calculator is `geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(coords_1, coords_2).miles`, where `coords_1` and `coords_2` are tuples.

To apply the function to each row in a dataframe, you need to use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def distancer(row):
    coords_1 = (row['pickup_lat'], row['pickup_long'])
    coords_2 = (row['dropoff_lat'], row['dropoff_long'])
    return geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(coords_1, coords_2).miles

df_post['pickup_dropoff_distance'] = df_post.apply(distancer, axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def distancer(row):
    coords_1 = (row['pickup_lat'], row['pickup_long'])
    coords_2 = (row['dropoff_lat'], row['dropoff_long'])
    return geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km
df_distance['pickup_dropoff_distance'] = df_distance.apply(distancer, axis=1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this it should work

```
df_post['lat1'] = radians(df_post['pickup_lat'].astype(float))
```

Comment: Ya i did that before i posted the question, it didnt work