# How to find the distance between two points given longitude and latitude in python-error?

Tags: python, distance, latitude-longitude

I have two locations with longitude and latitude given and I would like to get the distance between these points in python. My data set looks like below:

```
df_TEST = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['X'],
                     'Long': [ 28.63615701706],
                     'Lat': [ 41.0693487044612],
                     'Location1': ['Y'],
                     'Long1': [30.7158891385255],
                     'Lat1': [36.963486025471]})
```

My solution as suggested [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude)

```
 df_TEST['distance']=geopy.distance.geodesic(( df_TEST['Long'], 
 df_TEST['Lat']),(df_TEST['Long1'], df_TEST['Lat1'])).km
```

My error below please let me know how to fix this. Thank you.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [Documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.distance.geodesic) it accepts float tuple and not a pandas series tuple that you are trying to do here, try this instead:

```
df_TEST['distance']=geopy.distance.geodesic(( float(df_TEST['Long']), 
 float(df_TEST['Lat'])),(float(df_TEST['Long1']), float(df_TEST['Lat1']))).km
```

Comment: The `()` in `(float)` are unnecessary at best.

Comment: And I'm not sure if calling `float()` on a Series object will work. As far as I can tell, it doesn't overload the `__float__` method.

Comment: Yes it definitely will work as the series in this case only have a single element for each column, about (float) - I was recently using Java ;) so my bad I have updated the answer now @mkrieger1

Comment: df_TEST = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['X1','X2'],
                         'Long': [ 28.63615701706,76],
                         'Lat': [ 41.0693487044612,54],
                         'Location1': ['Y1','Y2'],
                         'Long1': [30.7158891385255,65],
                         'Lat1': [36.963486025471,45]}) In this case it is not working

Comment: Then it should be `float(df_TEST['Long'][0])` etc.

Comment: @melik obviously you **cannot typecaste a series to float** as I said above therefore what _mkrieger1_ said worked.

Comment: geopy.distance.geodesic(float(df_TEST['Long'][0]), 
 float(df_TEST['Lat'][0]),(float(df_TEST['Long1'][0]), float(df_TEST['Lat1'][0]))).km I get the same results what is the problem?

Comment: No problem@melik it's just a clarification for you