# How to find the distance between two points given longitude and latitude without do loop?

Tags: python, distance, latitude-longitude

I have two locations with longitude and latitude given and I would like to get the distance between these points in python. My data set looks like below:

```
 df_TEST = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['X1','X2'],
                     'Long': [ 28.63615701706,76],
                     'Lat': [ 41.0693487044612,54],
                     'Location1': ['Y1','Y2'],
                     'Long1': [30.7158891385255,65],
                     'Lat1': [36.963486025471,45]})
```

I would like to add a new column to this dataframe with below code but it works only for one row. I have a huge data set and I would like to add this column  without do loop. Solution suggested from 
[How to find the distance between two points given longitude and latitude in python-error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004295/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-points-given-longitude-and-latitude-in-pyth)
How can I do this?

```
 df_TEST['distance']=geopy.distance.geodesic(float(df_TEST['Long'] . 
[0]), float(df_TEST['Lat'][0]),(float(df_TEST['Long1'] . 
[0]),float(df_TEST['Lat1'][0]))).km
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply()` function on your DataFrame, to apply a function to each row of the DataFrame.

Here is the code:

```
def distance(row):
    return (geopy.distance.geodesic((row['Long'], row['Lat']), 
                                     row['Long1'], row['Lat1']).km)

df_TEST['distance']=df_TEST.apply(distance, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have missed something but what about

```
>>> df_TEST['distance_km'] = df_TEST.apply(
        lambda r: geopy.distance.geodesic(
            r.Long, r.Lat,  r.Long1, r.Lat1
        ).km,
        axis=1
    )
>>> df_TEST
  Location       Long        Lat Location1      Long1       Lat1  distance_km
0       X1  28.636157  41.069349        Y1  30.715889  36.963486  3221.113126
1       X2  76.000000  54.000000        Y2  65.000000  45.000000  5904.462593
```