# distance calculation between multiple sources and destinations using latitude and longitude

Tags: python, distance

i have data which has multiple sources and delivery locations and their respective latitude and longitude values, i need to calculate the distance (in km/miles) between each of the sources and destinations, below is the sources and destinations coordinates

```py
origin_coords = [
  '-33.8309, 151.0875', 
  '-33.77733, 151.119854']
destination_coords = [
  '-25.5789375305176, 134.359710693359', 
  '-12.46029472, 130.8423157', 
  '-33.87905884, 151.2432098']
```

can someone help me to execute it in python

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far. ?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geopy` package:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
for org, dst in zip(origin_coords, destination_coords):
    print(geodesic(org, dst).kilometers)
```

---

**(in Kms):**

```
1855.6690160383962
3131.115522557264
```

**Edit:**

If you want to find distance from each origin to the destination the use this:

```
import itertools 

coord_orig_2_dst = list(itertools.product(origin_coords, destination_coords)) # <-- will give 6 pairs
for idx, (org, dst) in enumerate(coord_orig_2_dst):

    if (idx+1)%(len(origin_coords)):
        print(f"\nposition from origin{(idx+1)//(len(origin_coords))} to destination")
    print(geodesic(org, dst).kilometers)
```

---

```
position from origin0 to destination
1855.6690160383962
3133.107252977121

position from origin1 to destination
15.3678706642723
1855.8745525856307

position from origin2 to destination
3131.115522557264
16.053573246669945
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

origin_coords = ['-33.8309, 151.0875', '-33.77733, 151.119854'] 
destination_coords = ['-25.5789375305176, 134.359710693359', '-12.46029472, 130.8423157', '-33.87905884, 151.2432098']

origin_coords = [[float(v.split(",")[0]), float(v.split(",")[1])] for v in origin_coords]
destination_coords = [[float(v.split(",")[0]), float(v.split(",")[1])] for v in destination_coords]

origin_coords = np.array([[radians(v[0]), radians(v[1])] for v in origin_coords])
destination_coords = np.array([[radians(v[0]), radians(v[1])] for v in destination_coords])

# distance in km.
def geodesic_dist(x, y):
  dlon = y[1] - x[1]
  dlat = y[0] - x[0]
  a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(x[0]) * cos(y[0]) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

  return 6373.0 * c

print(pairwise_distances(origin_coords, destination_coords, metric=geodesic_dist))
```

which yields

```
[[1854.93894877 3138.98807828   15.34816524]
 [1855.11802065 3136.96316526   16.06085592]]
```

See [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude) for details.