# How find the distance in meters between two points in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where, columns with subscript 1 are starting points and with 2 are end points.
I want to find a difference in kilometers between them.
I tried following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude/43211266#43211266) however got an error

```
import mpu
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'lat1': [39.92123,  39.93883,  39.93883,  39.91034,  39.91248],
        'lon1': [116.51172, 116.51135, 116.51135, 116.51627, 116.47186],
        'lat2': [np.nan,    39.92123,  39.93883,  39.93883,  39.91034],
        'lon2': [np.nan,   116.51172, 116.51135, 116.51135, 116.51627  ]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  


df['distance'] = mpu.haversine_distance((df.lat1, df.lon1), (df.lat2, df.lon2))
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You're not going to tell us what the error is?

Comment: @takendarkk Sorry, I added

Comment: The error is as expected:  result of passing Series instead of scalar values.

Comment: you are using a method that only works on _one_ pair of coordinates. If you want to vectorize this then [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.apply()` with lambda function so that you can pass the coordinates as scalar values instead of now passing 4 Pandas series to the function:

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: mpu.haversine_distance((x.lat1, x.lon1), (x.lat2, x.lon2)), axis=1)
```

You can also use `list(map(...))` for faster execution, as follows:

```
df['distance'] = list(map(mpu.haversine_distance, zip(df.lat1, df.lon1), zip(df.lat2, df.lon2)))
```

Comment: Thank you. But apply function will do it slowly as i have 1mln. rows. Are there any other faster alternatives?

Comment: @JohnMayer Ok, you can use `list(map(...)`.  Let me show you.

Comment: Thank you. I also found that vectorization can solve the problem. and the code will look like `np.vectorize(mpu.haversine_distance)((df.lat1, df.lon1), (df.lat2, df.lon2))`. or in this example vectorization cannot be applied?

Comment: @JohnMayer  [`np.vectorize()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is not really doing things vectorized.  You can see the doc saying "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."    Hence, it can't make improvement over looping.

Comment: I also tried option with `list(map(...))`, however got and error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`, and `data.apply(lambda x: mpu.haversine_distance((x.lat1, x.lon1), (x.lat2, x.lon2), axis=1)) ` (I added one bracket) has an error ` 'Series' object has no attribute 'lat1' `

Comment: @JohnMayer  Let me look at it and come back to you.  I also just noticed missing a bracket for the apply() function.  Please note the missing `)` should be after `x.lon2`.  I will further look at the list(map( issue.

Comment: @JohnMayer  Fixed also the `list(map(...))` issue now.  Both options now have no error caused by syntax now.    Now both show logical error of `lat1=116.51, but must be in [-90,+90]` .    This should be caused by the data.

Comment: Indeed latitude should be in this range, I updated the dataframe (just switched the numbers between latitude and longitude. However, now the same error that latitude should be in this range, however, I have NaN and this lies outside the range (dropping this row is not an option)

Comment: @JohnMayer  I think maybe you need to switch to use another tool that support your coordinate ranges. Anyway, it's also a problem for those tools to support NaN.  Maybe you have to drop those entries with NaN before passing to the tool.

Comment: @JohnMayer  Just for your info.  I benchmarked .`apply()` and `list(map(...))` with 5,000 coordinates,  `list(map(...))` is more than 12x times faster.