# Nearest latitude and longitude points in python

Tags: python, geolocation

I have a list of stations in List 1 and List 2
How do I find the closest stations to List 1 from List 2 ?

[list 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EuPg.png)

List 1

SS No   Latitude    Longtitude
977     23.141747   53.796469
946     23.398398   55.422916
742     23.615732   53.717952
980     23.633077   55.567046
660     23.6504     54.4007

List 2

SS No   Latitude    Longtitude
962     23.657571   53.703683
745     23.671971   52.955976
743    23.766849    53.770344
978    23.847163    52.809653
748    23.942166    52.16236
744    23.955817    52.790424
760    23.984592    55.55764
945    24.030256    55.844842
894    24.03511     53.891547
856    24.741601    55.80063
893    24.04123     53.899958
387    24.059988    51.748138
675    24.061578    53.417912
664    24.063978    51.76195

I can do this manually by mapping them on PowerBI but I am looking for a scalable solution and
Prefer Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geopy is your friend. It has functions that calculate the distance between coordinate pairs. Here's one approach:

```
from geopy import distance

s = {
    977: (23.141747, 53.796469),
    946: (23.398398, 55.422916),
    # etc etc
}

d = {
    962: (23.657571, 53.703683),
    745: (23.671971, 52.955976),
    743: (23.766849, 53.770344),
    # etc etc
}

for (ss, a) in s.items():
    best = None
    dist = None
    for (dd, b) in d.items():
        km = distance.distance(a, b).km
        if dist is None or km < dist:
            best = dd
            dist = km

    print(f'{ss} is nearest {best}: {dist} km')
```

If I run it with your example data I get:

```
977 is nearest 962: 57.909274476145846 km
946 is nearest 760: 66.3613771288571 km
742 is nearest 962: 4.857141728990575 km
980 is nearest 760: 38.94400553289674 km
660 is nearest 743: 65.56437761273963 km
```

If you need the distances from each of list 1 to each of list 2, you could try

```
sorted([[ss, dd, distance.distance(a, b).km] for (ss, a) in s.items()
        for (dd, b) in d.items()])
```

This gives a list of lists, ordered by the list 1 item first:

```
[[660, 387, 273.98088337893], 
 [660, 664, 272.6633222300461], 
 [660, 675, 109.98235440892797], 
 [660, 743, 65.56437761273963],

 # etc
```

Further ordering or grouping left as an exercice for the reader.

Comment: Thanks ! but how can I get multiple stations close by ? If i want the top 2 or 3 closest stations in list 2 to list 1?

Comment: For example :

977 is nearest to 962,: 57.909274476145846 km 760,: 57.909274476145846 km xyz: 57.909274476145846 km a

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you a start.

Comment: you are a BEAST. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to the previous question
[Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude) 
so, it could be claimed as duplicate.
Anyway, following Kurt Peek's answer, you could do:

```
import geopy.distance

def get_distnace(coords_1, coords_2):
    return geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

to get a function that returns the distance in 'km'. Then, given a couple of lists like yours, in the form

```
list1 = [[stat_name_1, lat_1, lon_1], [stat_name_1, lat_1, lon_1], ... ]

list2 = [[...], ... ]
```

you could probably do:

```
min_stat = get_distance(list1[0][1:], list2[0][1:])
for stat_1 in list1:
    coord_1 = stat_1[1:]
    for stat_2 in list2:
        coord_2 = stat_2[1:]
        min_stat = min(min_stat, get_distance(coord_1, coord_2)
```

Take it as a draft, an idea, to be debugged and tested before any application.