# How to calculate the distance between latitudes and longitudes of two stations in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, distance, latitude-longitude

I am having a dataframe with station info including latitudes and longitudes as follows:

```
start_lat   start_lng   end_lat      end_lng
41.877726   -87.654787  41.888716   -87.644448
41.930000   -87.700000  41.910000   -87.700000
41.910000   -87.690000  41.930000   -87.700000
```

and like wise.

I want to create a distance column from these info where the distance can be either in km or in miles for distance between these start and end points.

(As shared in the kin below, when I try to implement the SO answer, I encounter an error.)

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2
dlon = data.end_lng - data.start_lng
dlat = data.end_lat - data.start_lat

a = ((sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))**2)
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
data['distance'] = R * c
```

```js
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a8f8b698a81b> in <module>()
      2 dlon = data.end_lng - data.start_lng
      3 dlat = data.end_lat - data.start_lat
----> 4 a = ((sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))**2).apply(lambda x: float(x))
      5 c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
      6 data['distance'] = R * c

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    127         if len(self) == 1:
    128             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 129         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    130 
    131     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it out! I tried, but I think I am unable to use it properly: since I obtain a pandas series. Could you please help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the calculation on every row, one way is to use itterows (no guarantee on the distance calculation itself):

```
def get_distance(row, R = 6371): #km
    dlon = row[1]['end_lng'] - row[1]['start_lng']
    dlat = row[1]['end_lat'] - row[1]['start_lat']

    a = ((sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(row[1]['start_lat']) * cos(row[1]['end_lat']) * (sin(dlon/2))**2)
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    return R * c

data['distance'] = [get_distance(row) for row in data.iterrows()]
```