# Geopy distance between two point tuples of (lat, lon) coordinates

Tags: python, distance, geopandas, geopy

I've been trying to measure geographic distance between points in a GeoDataframe (gdb['geometry']) and one specific point, let's say, b_xy.

gdb['geometry'] is a geodatabase containing tuples of lon/lat coordinates as such:

| geometry |
| --- |
| POINT (-73.958 40.685) |
| POINT (-73.995 40.663) |
| POINT (-73.982 40.756) |

Whereas b_xy is a simple lon/lat coordinate:
(40.757280550000004, -73.98585503545917)

The code given to my professor from the textbook/tutorial he claims to be using for this example, is as such:

'd2b = lambda pt: cdist([(pt.x, pt.y)], [b_xy])[0][0]*10 #hasilnya degrees/radians
gdb['d2tsquare'] = gdb['geometry'].to_crs(tgt_crs)
.apply(d2b)'

which gives out a weird output that is presumably in degrees/radians, despite using a projected crs for `tgt_crs`

I've been trying to use [this](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/using-geopy-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points/) tutorial on measuring distances between two points, in meters. However, geopy.distance is unable to calculate from a tuple and can only perform singular inputs; it cannot accept data from a geodataframe.

I'm at a loss here for a method that works. Been thinking about making a loop for it but not sure where to start.

Comment: `geopy.distance` wants (lat,long); your `b_xy` is in that format, but the dataframe is not.  You'll need to swap them. `geopy.distance` absolutely wants to be given two tuples.

Answer (score 1):

This question is partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude). but to add some value here is what you want to do.

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print (geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

Output is : 279.35290160430094
which is the distance in km

Comment: This is what I was intending to do; the error I received is that geopy.distance.geodesic does not accept tuple inputs and does not accept pandas input

Comment: But you can see, we have passed the coords_1 and coords_2 as tuples. I can't get your point. are u trying to pass a single tuple to the geodesic() funcitno? like geodesic(tuple)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTM CRS to transform epsg:4386 co-ordinates into meters so distance calculation will be meters.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd
import io

gdb = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(
        pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(
                """geometry
POINT (-73.958 40.685)
POINT (-73.995 40.663)
POINT (-73.982 40.756)"""
            )
        )["geometry"],
        crs="epsg:4386",
    )
)

p = shapely.geometry.Point(
    -73.98585503545917,
    40.757280550000004,
)

gdb["distance"] = gdb.to_crs(gdb.estimate_utm_crs())["geometry"].distance(
    gpd.GeoSeries([p for _ in range(len(gdb))], crs=gdb.crs).to_crs(
        gdb.estimate_utm_crs()
    )
)

gdb
```

|  | geometry | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | POINT (-73.958 40.685) | 8361.98 |
| 1 | POINT (-73.995 40.663) | 10494.9 |
| 2 | POINT (-73.982 40.756) | 355.129 |