# How do I determine if a lat/lon pair falls within the radius of another lat/lon pair?

Tags: geolocation, gis, geospatial, geo

Here's an example of what I want to figure out:

- Device A is at 40.7128 / -74.0060 (lat/lon)
- Location B is at 40.730610 / -73.935242
- Radius = 10 miles

And the question:
*Is Device A within the radius around Location B?*

I don't care about the language or technology, just want to get the job done. I know some Python, JS, and Java.

Anyone know a good/efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the distance between the two points and check if it's inferior to the radius.

This thread gives some ideas on how to implement it in python: [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude)

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a latitude/longitude pair falls within a certain radius of another pair, you can use the Haversine formula, which calculates the distance between two points on the Earth's surface given their latitude and longitude coordinates. You can then compare the calculated distance to the radius to see if it's within the desired range. Here's a Java example of how to do this:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class LocationDistanceCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Coordinates for Device A (40.7128, -74.0060)
        double latA = 40.7128;
        double lonA = -74.0060;

        // Coordinates for Location B (40.730610, -73.935242)
        double latB = 40.730610;
        double lonB = -73.935242;

        // Radius in miles
        double radius = 10.0;

        // Check if Device A is within the radius of Location B
        boolean isWithinRadius = isWithinRadius(latA, lonA, latB, lonB, radius);

        if (isWithinRadius) {
            System.out.println("Device A is within the radius of Location B.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Device A is not within the radius of Location B.");
        }
    }

    // Calculate the distance between two latitude/longitude points using the Haversine formula
    public static double calculateDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        final int R = 6371; // Radius of the Earth in kilometers

        double lat1Rad = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lat2Rad = Math.toRadians(lat2);

        double deltaLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double deltaLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

        double a = Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) +
                   Math.cos(lat1Rad) * Math.cos(lat2Rad) *
                   Math.sin(deltaLon / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLon / 2);

        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

        double distance = R * c; // Distance in kilometers

        // Convert the distance to miles
        return distance * 0.621371;
    }

    // Check if a point is within a certain radius of another point
    public static boolean isWithinRadius(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, double radius) {
        double distance = calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
        return distance <= radius;
    }
}
```