# How to compute RMSE between two GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude) in Python

Tags: python

Good morning guys,

I would like to calculate the RMSE error between two gps coordinates (latitude and longitude).

Do you know if and how I can apply it to a known coordinate pair?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more detail about your problem ? You want to calculate RMSE between 2 type of latitude/longitude ? Example: RMSE between predicted latitude and ground truth latitude ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have GROUND TRUTH of pair Lat and Long for example (37.537008 ,   15.069104) and my prediction (37.536948 , 15.069109). The goal is to calculate RMSE error between these gps coordinates (also in terms of meters). Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RMSE of latitude/longitude:**

Using numpy you can do the following for longitude, and same for the latitude.

```py
import numpy as np
longitude = [1,2,3,4,5]
longitude_pred = [1.6,2.5,2.9,3,4.1]
 
MSE_longitude = np.square(np.subtract(longitude, longitude_pred)).mean() 
 
RMSE_longitude = np.sqrt(MSE)
```

If your coordinates is matrix of shape [2, n]:

```py
import numpy as np
long_lat = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]
long_lat_pred = [[1.6,2.5,2.9,3,4.1], [1.6,2.5,2.9,3,4.1]]
 
MSE_long_lat = np.square(np.subtract(long_lat, long_lat_pred)).mean(axis=1)
 
RMSE_long_lat = np.sqrt(MSE)
```

**Distance between coordinates in meters:**

To get a value in meters, you can for example calculate the distance between each points ((long, lat), (long_pred, lat_pred)) in meter using the Haversine formula. (More info on [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude))
But you can't get the RMSE in meters I think.

For one set of coordinates and predictions you can calculates the distance using geopy:

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print(geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km)

>>> 279.352901604
```

Then for a set of coordinates:

```py
coords_1 = np.array([[52.2296756, 21.0122287], [53.2296756, 22.0122287]])
coords_2 = np.array([[52.406374, 16.9251681], [51.406374, 18.9251681]])

distance_in_meters = [geodesic(coord1, coord2).km for coord1, coord2 in zip(coords_1, coords_2)]

print(distance_in_meters)

>>> [279.35290160430094, 292.3121626267748]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I wanted to calculate the error in meters?