# Distance between two geographical co-ordinates in 3D (including lat, long, depth)?

Tags: python

I am looking for the reliable relationship that can be used to compute the distance between two geographical points in 3D which include latitude, longitude and depth. I found the function ecefOffset in MATlab that can be used to compute the distance.

```
% MATLAB FUNCTION
[deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ] = ecefOffset(spheroid,lat1,lon1,h1,lat2,lon2,h2);
d = hypot(hypot(deltaX,deltaY),deltaZ);
```

But, I am looking for relationship in python.
May someone suggest me any possible way out!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude)

Comment: @adrianop01, this only limited to 2D, I am looking for 3D in python.