# Sort path of multiple points in shortest distance order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, distance

I have such a dataframe:

| id | lat | lon | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 51.0234 | 0.3467 | ... |
| 1 | 52.8762 | 0.2890 | ... |
| 2 | 54.0342 | 0.4510 | ... |
| 3 | 50.1237 | 0.1870 | ... |

and so on. There are multiple points like those in non x nor y order. I want to sort those points in the minimum distance order between points. I am using cKDTree for quick nearest-neighbor lookup to find neighbours of the current point and then I am trying to go to the next point and calculate the closest point except the previous one. I am tracking visited points in a list and in find_closest_point_idx checking if current point (actually index) is not in the list. This is my code:

```py
def calculate_shortest_path(df: pd.DataFrame, starting_point: np.array, ending point: np.array) -> pd.DataFrame:
    points = df.loc[:, ['lat', 'lon']].values
    current_point = starting_point

    tree = cKDTree(points)
    starting_idx = tree.query(current_point)[1]

    visited_indices = [starting_idx]
    while not np.array_equal(current_point, ending_point):
        closest_idx = find_closest_point_idx(visited_indices[-1], tree, visited_indices)
        if closest_idx is None:
            break
        visited_indices.append(closest_idx)
        current_point = points[closest_idx]

    return df.iloc[visited_indices]

def find_closest_point_idx(current_idx: int, tree: cKDTree, visited_indices: list) -> Union([int, None]):
    _, closest_indices = tree.query(tree.data[current_idx], k=len(tree.data))

    for idx in closest_indices:
        if idx not in visited_indices:
            return idx
    return None
```

This is the result when I plotted points in sorted order and connected them:

[Image of wrong connected line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUQxF.png)

[Closer look to connected points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWaKO.png)

[Another wrong line, the left most one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbaGJ.png)

Some points, seem to be skipped because the distance to them in current iteration is too far, so they are connected later when all of the other points have successfully been connected. How can I avoid such cases and improve the code. I thought about points optimization and points reduction, where I will cluster points in some small clusters and instead of 10 points I would create one point that is the mean of all the others. The problem here is that dataframe has other columns that are numerical as well as categorical and clustering them might be impossible (or maybe  I am wrong). The code also runs very long as my dataframe has many rows, is there any Python package or function in numpy, scipy or other that calucaltes it?

The next step would be to smooth the curve, but this is not the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already have an algorithm, which results in almost all points being ordered correctly, and a small minority of points being ordered completely wrong.

Comment: I suggest a very simple algorithm to run after the algorithm you already have: 1) Identify these "wronly-ordered" points; 2) For every wrongly-ordered point, find the best position to insert it in your sequence. If implemented very naively, this algorithm will run in time kn where n is the number of correctly-sequenced points and k is the number of outlier points. If that is too slow, you can improve by using your KDTree to make step 2) faster.

Comment: This looks like the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is a well studied problem and there are quite a few algorithms to solve it both exactly or approximately.

Comment: @aerobiomat The traveling salesman problem in all generality is quite a hard problem, but in the OP's case it's much much much simpler as the points are given by their 2-dimensional coordinates and if you look at the image, the points are positioned along a curve, which means you can easily eliminate almost all points when looking for a point's successor in the path.

Comment: @Stef Nevertheless, the chosen algorithm is a greedy solution to general traveling salesman problem, with nothing taking advantage of the "curve" distribution of the points. Therefore, the found solution falls in a classical pit of greedy algorithm for traveling salesman : if, for some reason, one point is missed (because there is a small loop in the curve for example. It should not happen if the curve is very "smooth" without noise, and if we start from one of the ends), then, exactly that happens: that missed point will be join only after all other are.

Comment: @Stef But indeed, as you stated here and in another comment, one should take advantage of the curve. I would deal with such a problem almost as a regression problem: finding the curve (or an approximation of it: line, piece-wise lines, parabolic or piecewise parabolic, or splines, ..) from the cloud of points. And then sorting the points from their projection on that curve. And then, maybe use a local traveling salesman solution on each sequence of 4 or 5 points, to make some local reordering

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the problem looks like Traveling Salesman Problem (with one difference, the salesman doesn't return to beginning at the end).

You can use for example `networkx` library to compute it:

```py
from math import atan2, cos, radians, sin, sqrt

import networkx as nx

# taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412565/10035985
def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # Approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    return R * c


tsp = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem
SA_tsp = nx.approximation.simulated_annealing_tsp

cost_func = lambda idx1, idx2: distance(
    df.loc[idx1, "lat"], df.loc[idx1, "lon"], df.loc[idx2, "lat"], df.loc[idx2, "lon"]
)

lst = df.index
# construct complete graph from `df.index` (each node is connected to each other node)
# assuming df.index is from 0 to N
G = nx.complete_graph(len(df.index))
for e in G.edges():
    idx1, idx2 = lst[e[0]], lst[e[1]]
    # each edge has custom weight (e.g. distance from going from df[idx1] to df[idx2])
    G[e[0]][e[1]]["weight"] = cost_func(idx1, idx2)

# compute TSP (this is taken from the example in their doc page)
# https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.traveling_salesman.traveling_salesman_problem.html
method = lambda G, wt: SA_tsp(G, "greedy", weight=wt, temp=500)

p = tsp(G, cycle=False, method=method)
# print "sorted" dataframe
print(df.loc[p])
```

Prints:

```
   id      lat     lon col1
2   2  54.0342  0.4510    c
1   1  52.8762  0.2890    b
0   0  51.0234  0.3467    a
3   3  50.1237  0.1870    d
```

---

Initial DF:

```
   id      lat     lon col1
0   0  51.0234  0.3467    a
1   1  52.8762  0.2890    b
2   2  54.0342  0.4510    c
3   3  50.1237  0.1870    d
```

Comment: Have you tested this solution with more than 4 points?

Comment: @Stef It should work. If speed is the problem, `networkx` has offers other heuristics to compute TSP.

Comment: This sounds like it doesn't make use of the geometric nature of the problem, and of the fact that the OP's points are already nicely located along a curve, so that the problem is actually much much much easier than the traveling salesman problem.